# Jersey JAX-RS register more controllers on embedded Jetty

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to implement a restful web service using Jersey JAX-RS.
I embedded a Jetty web server and wanted to register all the controllers on it.

I based on this example: 
https://nikgrozev.com/2014/10/16/rest-with-embedded-jetty-and-jersey-in-a-single-jar-step-by-step/

in which EntryPoint is the controller:

```
@Path("/entry-point")
public class EntryPoint {

  @GET
  @Path("test")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String test() {
    return "Test";
  }
}
```

and this is registered using the key name "**jersey.config.server.provider.classnames**" as follows:

```
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");

    Server jettyServer = new Server(8080);
    jettyServer.setHandler(context);

    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(
         org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

    // Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/class to load.

    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(
       "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
       EntryPoint.class.getCanonicalName());

    try {
        jettyServer.start();
        jettyServer.join();
    } finally {
        jettyServer.destroy();
    }
  }
}
```

How can I register many controllers?

If I add other controller classes as params I don't know what key name I must give to each one, because only "**jersey.config.server.provider.classnames**" seems to work and works once.
Thanks.

Comment: Can't give a full answer but can advice to look into ResourceConfig class from Jersey. I think answer is in this direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can only use the property once, you need to use a comma delimited list as the value `classOne, classTwo, classThree`.

Another option is to use the property `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` and just give it a package to recursively scan

```
jerseyServlet.setInitParam(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "my.package.to.scan");
```

See [ServerProperties](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.27/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html) for more properties you can set. Here `PROVIDER_PACAKGES` is a constant, whose string value is `jersey.config.server.provider.packages`. Same with the `classnames` property there is a constant `PROVIDER_CLASSNAMES`.

By declaring the package to scan, Jersey will scan that package *recursively* (by default) and register all `@Path` and `@Provider` annotated classes it finds in the scan.

Comment: For whatever reason, `PROVIDER_CLASSNAMES` works for me, but not `PROVIDER_PACKAGES`